# Laravel ajax not returning data

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble retrieving data from Controller using ajax
this is my code

the trigger

```
<select id="course_select" name="course_select" class="form-control" required autofocus value="{{old('course_select')}}" onchange="getCourse()">
```

The my ajax section

```
function getCourse(){
  var id=document.getElementById('course_select').value;
  alert(id);
  $.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:'getCourseLessons/'+id,
    datatype:'json',
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
      alert(data.lessons);
    }
  });
}
```

and my controller

```
public function getCourseLessons($id){
      $lessons = DB::table('lessons')->select('id','Lesson_name')->where('course_id','=',$id)->get();
      return response()->json(array('lessons'=>$lessons));
}
```

Results console.log(data)

```
console.log(data)
ReferenceError: data is not defined[Learn More]
```

My Routes.

```
Route::get('/getcourselessons/{id}','AdminController@getCourseLessons');
```

I will appreciate all the help i can get.

Comment: if it will hep am using laravel 5.5

Comment: `alert(data.lessons);` shows empty, is that it?

Comment: What error you are facing in XHR? Does it go into the method? Have you tried echoing?

Comment: yes AmmoPT am recieving no alerts so i cant know if its successful or Not

Comment: @rahulsm not yet let me try it  then i will let you know..

Comment: Open the network inspector and look at the response from the controller, does it have json that contains the lessons? Is it possible your query is returning nothing?

Comment: Are you getting the id in alert when you call the function?

Comment: can you dump `$lessons` ? it might be null ?

Comment: show how you put data on this select.

Comment: @Luminoslty tried loging the data it actually returns **console.log(data);
ReferenceError: data is not defined[Learn More]**

Comment: Paste the console.log output in your question?

Comment: @Rob i am getting the id in the alert

Comment: @KennedyNdegwa can you open the network inspector and screenshot the relevant information? (headers & response)

Comment: Okay, `print_r($id);die;` in the function and check if you are getting the id in the Network or not?

Comment: @KennedyNdegwa You said `am recieving no alerts so i cant know if its successful or Not ` which doesn't make sense. You have the `alert(data.lessons)` inside sucess function so if you're not getting this alert... it's not being successful. Implement `ajax.error` or double check that the URL is correct.

Comment: @AmmoPT what i meant was the alerts am getting are for the id but i am not getting the allert for the response.

Comment: @KennedyNdegwa I know, that's exactly what I was talking about, not the `id`.

Comment: @Luminoslty i am getting a 404 response i bet this might be the issue

Comment: @KennedyNdegwa it is 100% the issue. You're missing your route or you need to prefix your ajax request url with /

Comment: @DanielGale this what i am getting from my networks section **HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 13:06:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/json**

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the assist i finally cracked it it was a URL issue thats why i was getting the 404 message  i have marked the most correct answer as  i will also share the code for future reference by other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please check the route you used in Route/Web.php it should be like this

```
Route::get('getCourseLessons/{id}','YourController@getCourseLessons');
```

Check the controller.

```
public function getCourseLessons($id){
  $lessons = \DB::table('lessons')->select('id','Lesson_name')->where('course_id',$id)->get();
  return response()->json(array('lessons'=>$lessons));
}
```

As per your ajax code is ook but you can try this also.

```
function getCourse(){
  var id=$('#course_select').val();
  alert(id);
     $.ajax({
       type:'get',
       url:'{{url('getCourseLessons')}}/'+id,
       datatype:'json',
       success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
           alert(data.lessons);
        }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the assist i finally cracked it it was a URL issue thats why i was getting the 404 message  i have marked the most correct answer as  i will also share the code for future reference by other users.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="course_select" name="course_select" class="form-control"  onchange="getCourse()">
   <option>hi</option>
   <option>hello</option>
</select>
```

It seems that there is problem in your select as the above code will output
check the following

```
 value="{{old('course_select')}}"
```

and one more thing I can't see  CSRF

Add somewhere in your script

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
```

Comment: if he does {{csrf_field()}} isn't it .val()

Comment: yes and i might have to change the type from get to post

Answer (score 0):

try this bro change you `url` or `route`

```
function getCourse(){
 var id=document.getElementById('course_select').value;
 var url = '{{ url('getCourseLessons/')}}/'+id;
 alert(id);
 $.ajax({
 type:'get',
 url:url,
 datatype:'json',
  success:function(data){
   console.log(data);
   alert(data.lessons);
   }
  });
}
```

change your `route`

```
Route::get('getcourselessons/{id}','AdminController@getCourseLessons');
```

Comment: **HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 13:06:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/json**

Comment: how is your route?

Comment: try now you cant print data

Answer (score 0):

1- cheek your route

```
Route::get('/getCourseLessons/{id}','YourController@getCourseLessons');
```

2- change your Ajax attributes

```
function getCourse(){
  var id=document.getElementById('course_select').value;
  alert(id);
  $.ajax({
    url: '{{ url("getCourseLessons") }}',
    type:'get',
    datatype:'json',
     data: {
            "id": id,
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
          },
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
      alert(data.lessons);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have updated this is what i am still getting as a response

Comment: **HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 13:06:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/json**